# Custom Action Group in share point ribbon

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, custom-action, sharepoint-online

I have implement custom action group in share point from Below code.

```
<CustomActionGroup Id="Ribbon.Documents.CustomGroup"
                         Description="$Resources:bipDMSTemplate,grpCustomActionGroupDescription;"
                         Title="$Resources:bipDMSTemplate,grpCustomActionGroupName;"
                         Location="Ribbon.Library.Groups._children"
                         Sequence="100">
    </CustomActionGroup>
```

After deployment, custom action group does not visible in Ribbon.library. Can any one look in this ?

Comment: That location seems invalid. Take a look [Default Custom Action Locations and IDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb802730.aspx)